# textarea character count in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototypejs

I want to use [`observe_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002183) to give me the character count of the textarea, updated as you type. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="field">
  <%= observe_field :micropost_content,
      :function => "$('micropost_content').value.length" %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set the frequency option it becomes event based (onchange.) Try:

```
<%= observe_field :micropost_content, :frequency => 1,
      :function => "$('micropost_content').value.length" %>
```

Comment: Event based is what I want.. I want it to change immediately when you type a key. I tried setting the frequency to one second like you suggested, though, and it still isn't showing anything above the text box.

Comment: I think you need to change your function if you're using what's in your example, "$('micropost_content').value.length"; will just evaluate to some number, not do anything special. Try doing "alert('changed')" or something to see if it's working.